# PHP Session management when user abandons checkout then comes back again

Tags: php, session-variables

On the registration section of my website, users' details are stored in a PHP session. After payment, database entries are created from the information stored in the session.

Problem is, if the user somehow abandons the checkout process before completion, then does it again, the session will eventually contain the old as well as the new information, and put everything in the database.

Is there a simple way to prevent this ?

Comment: Can you show your $_SESSION variable schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the session when the user visit's the home page/checkout page so that all the old information will be cleared and they can try again. This can be done with a simple line of code at the homepage/checkoutpage:

```
$_SESSION['NAME OF SESSION'] = null;
```

Comment: No problem, Hope I help you out :)